# Regex: Select and delete all lines between 2 points

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to delete all those lines that starts with `<script type="application/ld+json">` and ends with `</script>`

For example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context":"https://schema.org",
"@type":"Article",

"mainEntityOfPage": {
"@type": "WebPage",
"@id": "https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/qualities-of-a-leader.html"
},

"headline": "Stiri stiintifice si tehnologice ",
"keywords": "stiri, stiintifice, tehnologice ",
"description": "Trebuie sa ai multe calitati de lider",
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="author" content="Redacción">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/qualities-of-a-leader.html",
"author": "admin",
"image": {
"@type": "ImageObject",
"url": "https://neculaifantanaru.com"
},

"datePublished": "2021-07-05T08:00:00+08:00",
   "dateModified": "2021-07-05T08:00:00+08:00",
   "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Neculai Fantanaru"
   },
}
</script>
```

I don't know why my regex doesn't work. I make a model of regex, and I replace with my tags:

**`(?<=FROM HERE).*?(?=TO HERE)`**

**So, my regex becomes:**

FIND: `(?<=<script type="application/ld+json">).*(?=</script>)`

Has anyone a better solution, or can update my regex with a better version?

Replace by: `(leave empty)`

Comment: Do you want to also match `<script></script>` tags or not?

Comment: yes, sure. All the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
^<script type="application/ld\+json">.*?</script>$
```

Changes:

- escaped `+` - `d+` meant one or more `d`'s and `+` wasn't matched
- changed `.*` to non-greedy `.*?` to make sure to match only content between same pair of tags in case there are more
- added `^` to match start of line and `$` to match the end since you mentioned that as a requirement

You need to run it with ". matches newline" option enabled.

Comment: Genuine question (still learning regex): Doesn't ^ and $ denote the start and end of the whole string being considered, in other words, only match if the whole string matches the pattern, not just for each line? Wouldn't a \n at the end denote the end of the line instead? And is this redundant really since XML tags represent complete blocks (if you don't mind a few unnecessary CRLFs left lying around afterwards)?

Comment: No, they don't. Most text editors either run regexes in multiline mode by default or include an option to run in that.  `^` `$` are line anchors in that case. `\A` and `\Z` match start/end of the string then, in a lot of engines. `\n` doesn't match all line endings, there are 2 different ones that are common. And you never know if it's redundant or not - XML or HTML doesn't have a requirement of being formatted in a beautiful way, there could easily be lines like `</script></html>`, for example. The user wrote beginning/end so I included these, but may want to skip them depending on the goal.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#multi Also note you should normall not regex XML/HTML in the 1st place, it only makes sense rarely to do so, e.g. when running a selection/replacement in this type of program. Otherwise you use proper parsing library.

Answer (score 0):

Short story - add a backslash `\+`.

```
(?<=<script type="application/ld\+json">).*(?=</script>)
```

Matching the tags too you may want to use:

```
<script type="application/ld\+json">.*</script>
```

So, you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<script type="application/ld\+json">.*</script>`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- Tick the *Wrap around* option
- Search mode: *Regular expression*
- Tick the *.matches newline* option
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk)

**Additional info:**

I'm sure you know - following characters have special meaning in regex (e.g. `+`):

```
., +, *, ?, ^, $, (, ), [, ], {, }, |, \.
```

To match a character having special meaning in regex, you need to use a escape sequence prefix with a backslash `(\)`. RegEx `\.` matches "."; RegEx `\+` matches "+" and RegEx `\(` matches "(".

You also need to use regex `\\` to match `\` (backslash).

Comment: your regex doesn't work. See this: https://snipboard.io/rVq6pw.jpg

Comment: @Just Me - tick ***. matches newline***

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `FIRST-PART[\s\S]*?(SECOND-PART)[\s\S]*?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**SO, in this case, the regex must be:**

`<script type="application/ld\+json">[\s\S]*?(</script>)[\s\S]*?`